# Get a json attribute with variable name in Postgres

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

not an SQL guru here.
Trying to write a query that gets a few columns of a table, and only the value "icon" of the json column below (named weather). I got to a pointwhere i can list all the attributes listed right after sessions, which are timestamps, but no luck in iterating them and joining to the rest of the table.
I also have the feeling that it wasn't very clever to store that value as an attribute name, especially as it's already stored in the "dt" value.

Can anybody confirm if this is best practice or not?
And could somebody help me get the "icon" value?

```
{
   "lat":43.6423,
   "lon":-72.2518,
   "timezone":"America/New_York",
   "timezone_offset":-14400,
   "sessions":{
      "1651078174":{
         "dt":1651078174,
         "sunrise":1651052825,
         "sunset":1651103155,
         "temp":48.45,
         "feels_like":43.63,
         "pressure":1009,
         "humidity":68,
         "dew_point":38.39,
         "uvi":5,
         "clouds":100,
         "visibility":10000,
         "wind_speed":11.5,
         "wind_deg":310,
         "weather":[
            {
               "id":804,
               "main":"Clouds",
               "description":"overcast clouds",
               "icon":"04d"
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: json with variable names are at best bad and tricky, json needs a fixed name: value structure to be handled, so it is best to redesisgn your json

Comment: Thanks @nbk 
I need comments like this to emphasize the bad practice. I'm working on a project where i need to update various stages of Production DB to Data Warehouse, and they expect me to sort out also this kind of bad data engineering issues, that are time consuming to say the least.

Comment: when you start with json, you such bad design but basically replace "1651078174" with session_time = "1651078174" , session_data: ..... and everything is fine as far a s i can see, don't have dynamic names, else extracting becomes a nightmare

Comment: I see, but i cannot do the redesign of this. I can tell who's in charge to do so. Still if there is a way to iterate through all the different values it would be nice to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only 1 icon and multiple sessions you can run

if you have multiple icon you need to apply anothe CTE layer to extract them with json_Each

for more json function see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html

> ```
> wITH CTE AS (
>
> select value from json_each('{
>    "lat":43.6423,
>    "lon":-72.2518,
>    "timezone":"America/New_York",
>    "timezone_offset":-14400,
>    "sessions":{
>       "1651078174":{
>          "dt":1651078174,
>          "sunrise":1651052825,
>          "sunset":1651103155,
>          "temp":48.45,
>          "feels_like":43.63,
>          "pressure":1009,
>          "humidity":68,
>          "dew_point":38.39,
>          "uvi":5,
>          "clouds":100,
>          "visibility":10000,
>          "wind_speed":11.5,
>          "wind_deg":310,
>          "weather":[
>             {
>                "id":804,
>                "main":"Clouds",
>                "description":"overcast clouds",
>                "icon":"04d"
>             }
>          ]
>       }
>    }
> }
> ') WHERE key = 'sessions')
>  
> SELECT json_data.key session,
> json_data.value-> 'weather' -> 0 ->> 'icon'  FROM CTE,json_each(CTE.value) json_data
> ```

> ```
> session    | ?column?
> :--------- | :-------
> 1651078174 | 04d
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=e5cd30c1905a23a88515b415486340fe)*

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer and your time.  This returns:
SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "session"

Comment: check your postgres version and see if it is the same as in the fiddle, as i already told you json is bad, and you need all the function postgres provides, but some come onl in the latest version